# java look for a substring in a string using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

This code doesn't work.  Help fix it please.................................................................................................................

```
    /**
       Recursive method for looking for a substring in a string.
       @param text look in
       @param target look for as substring
       @return true if target is a substring of text
     */
    public static boolean find(String text, String target)
    {
        //-----------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 4
        // 1. base case: null 
        if (text == null) {return false;}        
        //2. base case: target too long 
        if (target.length() > text.length()) {return false;}
        //3. base case: same length 
        if (text.length() == target.length()) {return false;}
        //4. base case: startsWith  OR 5. recursive case
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I don't see in recursion here. I think your code in incomplete

Comment: What you try to achieve? What error you getting?

Comment: Predecessors are all spot on, I would add : in first base case you should be testing both, the `text` and the `target` for null, not only one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    /**
Recursive method for looking for a substring in a string.
@param text look in
@param target look for as substring
@return true if target is a substring of text
*/
public static boolean find(String text, String target)
{
 //-----------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 4
 // 1. base case: null 
 if (text == null || target == null) {return false;}  // added target null check       
 //2. base case: target too long 
 if (target.length() > text.length()) {return false;}
 //3. base case: same length 
 if (text.length() == target.length()) {return text.equals(target);}
 //4. base case: startsWith  OR 5. recursive case
 return text.startsWith(target) || find(text.substring(1) , target);
}
```

Comment: You really should be checking both `text` and `target` for null in 1. base case, or you could get an exception.

Comment: Yeah but this looks like a homework question.. so I stuck to the structure closely, as text is the thing being modified in the recursion its good practice to have proper base cases for it

Comment: It surely does look like a homework. That would enforce me even more to have it made that way that it would never drop me out. I consider the structure base cases are created by teacher, I would think any code was inserted by the student already, whereas he might think he struggles with the last line only.