# recursive substring search java

Tags: java, recursion, substr

I am trying to do a recursive search to check whether a sub string appears in a main string. It will return false if it doesn't exist in it, and it will return true if it does. Im not allowed to use the containcs() method in java

this is what i have tried so far

```
public boolean myContains(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;
    if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty())
        return false;
    //int remain= s2.substring(s1);
    return myContains(s1, s2.substring(1));
}
```

the call method looks like this

```
System.out.println( test.myContains("an", "banana"));
```

Comment: You have 3 code paths: false, false or `myContains` (which can be false or false). So clearly it will always return false.

Comment: While it's probably bending the rules a bit you could simply do `if (!s2.equals(s2.replaceFirst(s1, "")))`. But that probably wouldn't go to well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java look for a substring in a string using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138865/java-look-for-a-substring-in-a-string-using-recursion)

Comment: As a hint - you have a "startsWith()" method available on String. That may be useful.

Comment: On a side note you can combine the first 2 branches into if(s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.isEmpty()  || s2.isEmpty())
        return false;

Comment: Why don't you use `for loop` instead of recustion?

Comment: learning the basics of recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if s2 start with s1. If yes return true. If not remove the first char of s2 and redo the test.

I think this is what you've tried. But you missed the block where you check if s2 start with s1 and then return true

```
public boolean myContains(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;
    if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty())
        return false;
    if(s2.startsWith(s1))
        return true;
    return myContains(s1, s2.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks that did it, i was just missing that last if() statement

Answer (score 1):

If you are supposed to implement everything yourself this should work too

```
public boolean myContains(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;
    if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty())
        return false;
    if(s1.length() > s2.length())
        return false;

    boolean contains = true;
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
       if(s1.charAt(i)!=s2.charAt(i)){
          contains=false; 
          break;
       }
    }
    if(contains == true){return contains;}
    return myContains(s1, s2.substring(1));
}
```